# how to start php calendar on current month of viewer

Tags: php, date, calendar, isset

im trying to set up the calendar from http://davidwalsh.name/php-calendar-controls. hes provided some great code and on paper it seems to be perfect for what i need. but im a little rusty with my php and im getting some errors. its kind of an old blog post so i thought i might get a faster response on here. heres the code:

```
<?php

/* draws a calendar */
function draw_calendar($month,$year){

/* draw table */
$calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

/* table headings */
$headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

/* days and weeks vars now ... */
$running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
$days_in_this_week = 1;
$day_counter = 0;
$dates_array = array();

/* row for week one */
$calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

/* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
endfor;

/* keep going with days.... */
for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
        /* add in the day number */
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

        /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
        $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6):
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        endif;
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
endfor;

/* finish the rest of the days in the week */
if($days_in_this_week < 8):
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np"> </td>';
    endfor;
endif;

/* final row */
$calendar.= '</tr>';

/* end the table */
$calendar.= '</table>';

/* all done, return result */
return $calendar;
}



/* date settings */
$month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

/* select month control */
$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
$select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';

/* select year control */
$year_range = 7;
$select_year_control = '<select name="year" id="year">';
for($x = ($year-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($year+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
$select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
}
$select_year_control.= '</select>';

/* "next month" control */
$next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next Month >></a>';

/* "previous month" control */
$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.    ($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control"><<  Previous Month</a>';

/* bringing the controls together */
$controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.' <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" />      '.$previous_month_link.'     '.$next_month_link.' </form>';


?>
```

i get an error when the calendar is first loaded: Notice: Undefined index: month in C:\wamp\www\david walsh calendar\draw_calendar.php on line 70 and for year on line 71.

i tried doing something like:

```
if(!isset($month)){
$month = date(‘n’);
} else{
$month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date(‘m’));

}
```

but that didnt work it loads correct but then the calendar buttons stop working to go to the next or previous month. is there anyway to make the calendar load on the current month and year and still allow the next and previous month buttons to work?

thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line **70** and **71** to :

```
/* date settings */
$month = (int) (isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
$year = (int)  (isset($_GET['year']) ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));
```

And add at the end of your file :

```
echo $controls;
echo draw_calendar($month,$year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your code:

```
echo $controls; echo draw_calendar($month,$year);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo $mth[$mo]." ".$yr;
?>
```

If that doesn't work please refer to this for more help:
http://www.epctutorials.com/